# Prism and MVVM Light Toolkit

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I'm trying to put Prism (just for CompositeUI) and MVVM Light Toolkit (for MVVM architecture =D) working together, but I'm getting some troubles with the Light ViewModelLocator.
When we use the locator into a "simple" WPF application, we can use an application resource on App.xaml, like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

But when we are using Prism, our business code is inside the Module project, and it doesn't have an App.xaml, then I tried to put that resource inside the View resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

It just turned off my Design mode (and also runtime) errors, but the View doesn't appear in the region assigned to it.

Somebody already tried to do something like this?
Is it possible to put Prism and MVVM Light working together?

This is my "full" code:

(ViewLight.xaml)

```
<Window x:Class="TryERP2.Financeiro.View.ViewLight"
    ... a lot of NS ...
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TryERP2.Financeiro.ViewModel"
    d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="245" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Light, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <Button Content="{Binding MyButtonText}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewLightModel.cs:

```
public class ViewLightModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewLightModel()
    { }

    public const string MyButtonTextPropertyName = "MyButtonText";
    private string _myButtonText = "Button Text";

    public string MyButtonText
    {
        get
        { return _myButtonText; }

        set
        {
            if (_myButtonText == value)
            { return; }

            _myButtonText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(MyButtonTextPropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Financeiro.cs (The module initializer class ... Partially shown ... Just where I register and "invoke" the views):

```
        var container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
        container.RegisterType<Object, ViewLight>("ViewLight");

        var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
        var main = new Uri("ViewLight", UriKind.Relative);
        regionManager.RequestNavigate("Desktop", main);
```

A "normal" MVVM Light Application has an App.xaml file, that (I think) isn't used in Prism modules Views. That file has this structure:

```
<Application x:Class="TryERP2.Financeiro.App"
         ... a lot of NS ...
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TryERP2.Financeiro.ViewModel"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Application.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

That's what happen when I execute my application. The View that was on the module should be loaded into this blank space, showing its Button, but nothing happened:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/818/capturarwy.png

When I try to change this view and put in its place a "simple view" (not using MVVMLight) it works perfectly, like shown in the picture below:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/capturar1a.png

Comment: What container do you use? MEF or Unity? Can you post code for your view codebehind and ViewModel codebehind? Also, code on how you inject V-VM into region. MVVMLight, design data, etc is separate issues you deal with in PRISM/Silverlight. View not showing is most likely composition error

Comment: I'm using Unity. I'll post the whole code by editing the question.

Comment: There is no codebehind on the View, except the default code.
Do you think an explained screenshot of the running application would be helpful?

Comment: I tried to add some direct images, but I'm a new user and new users aren't allowed to post images, then I upload them to ImageShack and share theirs link here. Feel free to edit the question and add the imagens. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. I made a big mistake.
As you may have noticed, I'm building a Ribbon Application, and I'm trying to show the controls under a blank Region.
The items that can be displayed there are Controls. It wasn't working because I was trying to display a Window:

```
<Window x:Class="TryERP2.Financeiro.View.ViewLight"
... a lot of NS ...
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TryERP2.Financeiro.ViewModel"
d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="245" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
... etc
```

I fixed it by changing it to an User Control instead a Window, and it worked perfectly.

My new ViewLight.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TryERP2.Financeiro.View.ViewLight"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TryERP2.Financeiro.ViewModel"

        d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="245">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Light, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <Button Content="{Binding MyButtonText}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My new ViewLight.xaml.cs (Code-behind):

```
public partial class ViewLight : UserControl
{
    public ViewLight()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the ViewModel is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

In ViewLight.xaml you should change

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

to

```
<Window.Resources>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Because Window.Resources is already a ResourceDictionary, and you create an another in it. You cannot access Locator resource here:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Light, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Another option is to use MergedDictionary.

Comment: Hi... I had already tried to remove the <ResourceDictionary> tag, but this had no effect. Regarding the binding, I just had changed it to the <Grid> tag because I was getting an error. The original location of the DataContext property was the <Window> tag.

Comment: When it was in the Window tag, I got this errors message: "Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive.". It had worked on a simple MvvmLight application, where the resource were located in the <Application.Resources> tag.

Comment: what error did you have? check the output in vs (in debug mode) to capture binding errors.

Comment: the Grid and the Locator resource sits in the same xaml?

Comment: The "output" didn't give any error message. The error that I said appeared in the "Exception Window" -> [Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/210/91503502.png/)

Comment: because there is no Locator while you are creating the Window. This image you posted is different than your example. Set the datacontext on the Grid.

Comment: Just now, using the DataContext in the GRID tag (not Window), I was debugging the code and I realized that both the code of the Locator and ViewModel were executed successfully. I just couldn't understand why the View didn't appear under the designated Region.

Comment: I know that there is no Locator while I am creating the Window. That place is just the default place for DataContext of the MVVMLight framework, and I had already understood why it didn't work in that way. That's the reason why I tried to put the DataContext under the grid tag, and as I said, it (partially) worked.